# While loops (Python)

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a while loop that returns the number of 'rushes' it takes to get up a hill.
The size of the hill is the 'slope height' and the height run up is the 'rush_height_gain' minus the 'back_sliding'.

The code below works for:

```
ans = num_rushes(15, 10, 5)
print(ans)
```

which prints 1

and

```
ans = num_rushes(100, 15,7)
print(ans)
```

which prints 2

and

```
ans = num_rushes(10, 10, 9)
print(ans)
```

which prints 12

but returns the wrong answer for

```
ans = num_rushes(100, 10, 0)
print(ans)
```

which should print 10, but instead prints 9

I'm not sure why this is, and any help would be greatly appreciated

```
def num_rushes(slope_height, rush_height_gain, back_sliding):
    current_height = 0
    rushes = 0
    while current_height < slope_height:

        if rush_height_gain == slope_height:
            rushes+=1
            return rushes

        elif current_height < slope_height:

            if current_height == slope_height:
                return rushes

            else:
                a = rush_height_gain - back_sliding
                current_height += a

            if current_height == slope_height:
                return rushes

            elif current_height > slope_height:
                return rushes

            else:
                rushes+=1


    return (rushes)
```

Comment: What is the method supposed to do?  Most people don't want to guess.

Comment: Could you add the real and expected outputs?

Comment: http://pythonfiddle.com/rushes-quiz-work/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question properly, I think what you're looking for is:

```
def num_rushes(slope_height, rush_height_gain, back_sliding):
    if rush_height_gain < slope_height and rush_height_gain - back_sliding < 1:
        raise Exception("this is not going to work very well")
    current_height = rushes = 0
    while current_height < slope_height:
        rushes += 1
        current_height += rush_height_gain
        if current_height >= slope_height:
            break
        current_height -= back_sliding
    return rushes
```

After each uphill "rush", you check to see if you've reached the top. If so, you're done, if not, you slide down a bit and go again! As @perreal noted in his link in a comment to the original post, if you slide down more than you slide up and don't get up all the way the first time, you're going to have a problem. You might want to throw an exception in those cases.

Comment: @user2101517 no trouble. Python is fun!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is this statement:

```
        if current_height == slope_height:
            return rushes
```

When `back_sliding` is `0`, then on the tenth iteration, `current_height` goes from `90` to `100`. Then the check returns true, and `9` is returned before it's incremented.

Answer (score 0):

```
def num_rushes(slope_height, rush_height_gain, back_sliding):

    current_height = 0
    rushes = 0

    while current_height < slope_height:

        current_height += rush_height_gain
        rushes += 1

        if current_height < slope_height:
            current_height -= back_sliding

    return rushes
```